# displaying image from php myadmin database using asp.net gridview and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

the first pictures shows that the address is saved on my database. the 2nd shows my declaration of "product_image" on my database. the 3rd is the how i print the image on my gridview. and the 4th is the result. there is no image of the picture that i called. help me please. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, Here you are storing **Physical path** into database that's why it is creating problem, when you are providing full path like `C:\user\xx\xx` the asp.net application is not able to find those Images,Also this will create problem when you will deploy your application on production.The solution is to store **Relative path** based on current directory into database. [Use this link for more information](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142013/There-is-something-about-Paths-for-Asp-net-beginne)